# I need to replace my all the characters except ( ,* and +

Tags: python

For example in this below string

```
inParkBrake != 1 * inParamABAFunc= AVL * (ABA_Actv_Stat=NACT + ABA_Actv_Stat=SNA + ABA_Actv_Stat=ERR)
```

I need

- `inParkBrake != 1` to be replaced with 'a'
- `inParamABAFunc= AVL` to be replaced with 'b'
- `ABA_Actv_Stat=NACT` to be replaced with 'c'
- `ABA_Actv_Stat=SNA` to be replaced with 'd'
- `ABA_Actv_Stat=ERR` to be replaced with 'e'

Expected Output ->

```
a * b * (c + d + e)
```

After this I am going to expand using expand function

```
import sympy
from sympy import expand, symbols
a, b, c, d, e = symbols('a b c d e')
print(expand(a*b*(c+d+e)))
```

The output for the above is

```
a*b*c + a*b*d + a*b*e
```

Now all the values are substitued back

That is

```
inParkBrake != 1 * inParamABAFunc= AVL * ABA_Actv_Stat=NACT + inParkBrake != 1 * inParamABAFunc= AVL * ABA_Actv_Stat=SNA + inParkBrake != 1 * inParamABAFunc= AVL * ABA_Actv_Stat=ERR
```

Comment: Why you do not use `replace()` method of strings? `s='your string'`, `s = s.replace("inParkBrake != 1", "a").replace("inParamABAFunc= AVL", "b")...`

Comment: It can be differnt too
 Example1 : paramVehCabType=Two Door AND (DriverDoor=OPEN,PassengerDoor!=OPEN, LHD) OR (DriverDoor!=OPEN,PassengerDoor=OPEN, RHD)
Example2 : Rear Door=Open and PkBrk_Stat_SCH!=ENG and Veh Speed >= 10km/h